# Health decreasing for no apparent reason

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I am playing Dragonborn DLC. I am currently going through one of the black books quests and even though I am not fighting my health bar keeps going down. I can heal back up to full again but it keeps disappearing. If I do not heal I will die in about 30 seconds.

I have no disease or nothing is visible anyway, no clue as to what's wrong. I can leave the black book quest or fast travel to a different location or rest for 24 hours but still the health disappears.

Comment: are you sure this isn't the black book where being in the dark is lethal? you have to stay inside the moving lighted areas.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem! I went into the "Sallow Regent" black book (and another one immediately  after) to reset skills and change the power for sallow reagent. Struggled with trying to fix it for about an hour because my last clean save was 13 levels before. 
BOTTOM LINE:

1. Go into Sallow Regent. in lighted areas you should take no damage.
2. Go to a dark area. you should start taking damage over time.
3. Open your inventory and read the Sallow Regent to return to Solstheim.

That solved it for me. Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 2):

I vaguely recall this happening to me (it was during the first black book quest, I think). I had enough health that it didn't really affect me, although the sound made by the spell was a bit annoying.

Once I finished the quest and left the dungeon, I restarted my game and the issue went away. Maybe that would work for you as well?

Comment: I had this problem last night so left it and turned off the xbox. When I started the game this morning I had the same problem and still have now.

Answer (score 2):

The book at the end of the sallow regent level where you choose one of three powers - you need to look **at** that book and it will show "to solstheim". Press <kbd>X</kbd>.

I had to do it twice in order to get the glitch to clear

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me. It seems to be a glitch related to one of the quests where, when visiting Apocrypha, you take damage whenever you stray off the lighted path. (Sorry, forget the Quest name, I played this a couple months ago). For some reason, the game doesn't recognize that you're no longer in Apocrypha and continues to drain your health, making that annoying crackling noise that sounds like a burning fire.

Like others, I found the only solution was to quit and revert to a previously saved game.