# Health lowering but no disease in my active effects

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My health was at 175, now it's at 150. I have not changed armor or necklaces. If I go to a temple and get a blessing, my health goes back to 175. But then it will drop back down again after a day or two. And under my active effects it's not showing any diseases. Does anyone know what is going on?

I'm playing on the Xbox 360.

Comment: I've also been dealing with this for a while. I tried treating it like Vampirism, but I can't get the quest Rising at Dawn to activate.

Comment: Possibly related: [Health decreasing for no apparent reason](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/98595/4797)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like [Fortify Health](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Fortify_Health_%28Skyrim%29) where your health is temporarily boosted thanks to enchantments/effects of equipment and potions

> Fortify Health is an enchantment and an alchemical effect that temporarily increases the maximum health for a limited time.

This would explain why your health is boosted but then after a while it drops. Salvaged/bought [Fortify Health Potions](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Potions_%28Skyrim%29#Fortify_Health) normally have the effect last for 60 seconds.

There is a [Blessing of Arkay](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Blessing_%28Skyrim%29#Blessings) which

> Increases your health by 25 points.

Which would explain it and your health is dropping by 25 points because the blessing has worn off. if you keep an eye on the time you should notice the change after eight real-time hours of gameplay. if you check the Active Effects category of your Spells Menu you should see "Blessing of Arkay" there

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replying so quickly. while I was waiting for a reply I got the blessing of Talos and then Did the blessing of Arkay again... and that's exactly what happened. Thank you for answering my very stupid question :) i'm going to go hide under a rock now. lol

Comment: Don't worry about asking stupid questions. Loads of people have been wondering about stuff like this.

iirc, some of the more common healing potions also have a fortify health component. So that can also be the cause of increased/lowered max health.